# How to enable gerrit hooks?

Tags: git, docker, hook, gerrit

I am running `gerrit` on `dockers`. I am trying to use the `patchset-created` [hook](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html) in gerrit. But am stuck in the initial step itself.

When gerrit is initialized in the `GERRIT_SITE` directory, I cannot find the `hooks` directory present there where the `patchset-created` hook should be present.

I later installed `gerrit` on my local machine itself, thinking probably `dockers` is the problem. Still, I cannot find the `hooks` directory except the one present in the `git` folder which is a part of git-hooks. The document is not clear on how to configure `hooks`.

I need some guidance regarding how to get the `hooks` folder? How to enable it?  If any changes are to be made to `gerrit.config`?

Comment: "Dockers" are shoes. The technique that you are using is called "Docker". ;-)

Comment: Ooops :P will correct myself here on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to create the `hooks/` directory and place the (executable) `patchset-created` file in there. IIRC you have to start Gerrit afterwards.

`mkdir` is the magic command, but I guess that you know it.

You can btw. also configure Gerrit to search for hook files in a different directory in the [`[hooks]`](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#hooks) section of `gerrit.config`.

Comment: Oh okay... I was thinking on terms of some configuration for the directory to appear itself... Thanks again:)

Comment: Nah, restart of entire gerrit wasn't needed (tested on 2.16.6).